# robots.txt proper way to set it up

Tags: robots.txt

If you want to allow all search engines to crawl a site and only block one specific folder, is this correct?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder_name/
```

If you don't want to block any folder then is this the correct way?

```
User-agent: *
Allow:
```

Answer (score 1):

*Only time you ever need to use allow is for **overriding previous rules**.*

Generally webmasters will never need to use Allow because it is assumed true unless a Disallow is found that overwrites that ruling.

*File or Folder within a blocked Folder*

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /simon-hayter/
Allow: /simon-hayter/rocks.html
```

Take a look at the above example, the only time that you will ever need to use allow and disallow together is when you have a situation where you are blocking a file, directory or bot previously, the above situation is when you block a folder but want to allow crawlers access a file within that folder, but keep everything else blocked.

*Other Situations*

Other situations may be that you want to deny all search engines apart from Google... then your robot.txt might look something like this:

```
# Block all crawlers
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

# Allow Google
User-agent: Googlebot 
Allow: /
```

*WordPress Sites will generally want to use something like this:*

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

The reason why many SEO Guru's recommend that `admin-ajax.php` is set to allow despite it being located in the administration folder of WordPress is because many WP plugins use AJAX on the front end.

Comment: So this is perfectly fine as its what I'm using for my Word Press sites and it won't block any bot?                                                                                User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/

Comment: @Scott Yep you can use that or the one I just added to my answer :)